# error running app to test it on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

thanks for helping and apologize about my english.

I have a problem. Android studio: When i try to test my app in my phone conected to the PC, I run the app and I optain this error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

**This is my build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.anticoagulacionoralagssur"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        release {
            multiDexEnabled true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
//compile possible .jar files in the libs directory...
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//Google Play Services for Google Cloud Messaging and Google Maps...
//Firebase for push notifications
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
}


//To enable push notifications using Firebase:
//1) Download google-services.json file from Firebase control panel
//2) Copy google-services.json file into the /app directory of your project
//3) Uncomment the following line:

//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**This is the message on the Gradle Console:**

> Running dex as a separate process.
>
> To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap. It
>   currently       has 1024 MB. For faster builds, increase the maximum
>   heap size for the Gradle daemon to at least 2560 MB (based on the
>   dexOptions.javaMaxHeapSize = 2048M). To do this set
>   org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2560M in the project gradle.properties. For
>   more information see
>   https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html
>
> :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException Try: Run with --stacktrace
>   option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to
>   get more log output. BUILD FAILED

How can fix it?

Thanks again.

Comment: find gradle.properties file in your project folder
and add this line
`org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2560M`

Comment: add this `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'` in your dependencies

Comment: calvinfly, how must I add that line?

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove if any unnecessary dependency . and go in build folder and remove all four [image]

and try to run again i hope this will help you

you can find your dependencies here may be some can be removed if you are taking spwcific maps and base then why are you using whole playservice[image]

Comment: Thanks Ashish, so, I must remove those 4 folders. But i do not understand how to remove any unnecessary dependency.

Comment: Ok, i understand...do you advice me to remove base and maps, or the whole playservice?

Comment: removed whole play service and the folders, same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean and rebuild your project that might help. If still the problem persists then I will recommend you to use proguard, as you are using so many dependencies. Here is the link [on how to use proguard](http://www.cuelogic.com/blog/how-to-use-proguard-in-android-2/) in android.

Considering the fact that you have already enabled proguard following the link, you should add the following lines to your ***proguard-rules.pro*** file

```
-keep class .R
-dontwarn com.google.**
-keep class android.support.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
-keep interface android.support.** { *; }
```

That should work.

Comment: What  i must write in the proguard file?

Comment: I have edited the answer accordingly. Just try it once and do tell if it works.